# Can OLS be considered an optimization technique?

Tags: regression, optimization, least-squares, terminology

Can ordinary least squares estimation be considered an optimization technique? If so, how can I explain this?

Note:

From an AI perspective, supervised learning involves finding a hypothesis function $h_\vec{w}(\vec{x})$ that approximates the true nature between predictor variables and the predicted variable. Let some set of functions with the same model representation define the hypothesis space $\mathbb{H}$ (That is we hypothesise the true relationship to be a linear function of inputs or a quadratic function of inputs and so forth). The objective is to find the model $h\in\mathbb{H}$ that optimally maps inputs to outputs. This is done by application of some technique to finds optimal values for the adjustable parameters $\vec{w}$ that defines the function $h_w(\vec{x})$. In AI we call this parameter optimization. A parameter optimization technique/model inducer/learning algorithm would for example be the back propagation algorithm.

OLS is used to find/estimate for $\beta$ parameters that defines the linear regression line that *optimally* maps predictor variables to output variables. This would be parameter optimization in the scenario above.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "optimization technique"? That phrase would usually refer to something like [this section of the wikipedia page on optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization#Computational_optimization_techniques) but, based on the answers you've received, others are interpreting it another way. Just to clarify, if you mean it in the way asserted by the link, then the answer is certainly "No"; OLS is an estimation technique.

Comment: I dunno.  All optimization techniques minimize functions of a particular form.  So simplex won't minimize non-linear functions and Nelder-Mead won't minimize various horrible functions.  Under a strained reading of the word "optimize", OLS is an optimization technique for a very particular class of functions.

Comment: @Patrick, First of all, Nelder-Mead and "simplex" refer to the same thing and they most certainly will optimize a non-linear function (see, e.g. [pages 2-4 here](http://www.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~jasoneg/Stat406/lab10.pdf)). The various optimization techniques (e.g. Simplex, Newton's, CG, etc..) all are used as general-purpose algorithms for finding local extrema - none of them are inherently linked to a particular optimization _problem_. But, you are right that some algorithms are better for certain situations (e.g. derivative based algorithms are MUCH faster for convex, unimodal problems).

Comment: @Entropy Because the ambiguity in your question is leading to controversy, please edit it to clarify your meaning of "optimization technique."  Some kind of improvement of this nature is needed so that we can keep this thread open.

Comment: @Macro - I was referring to Dantzig's linear optimization algorithm called the "simplex method" which I've always called just "simplex".  I thought it would be clear in context ("won't work on non-linear functions").

Comment: I have upvoted the question as a positive response to the substantial edit. However, it strikes me that the question now contains its own answer: the edit appears to argue that essentially all parameter-fitting exercises are "optimization techniques"--we could almost take this as an (idiosyncratic) definition--and thus it concludes that OLS, as a parameter-fitting technique, is one of them.  This appears to leave us either with nothing to say or to argue about what "optimization technique" ought to mean. Alas, neither of these is a constructive activity. Should we just close this question?

Comment: @whuber, I agree. This seems to be a mixture of 1) 'Not constructive' since it seems to answer itself and has lead to some (non-statistical) debate - as you said, 2) 'Too localized' since it uses a specialized definition of the term "optimization technique" and it's not clear how this will assist any future readers in their statistical queries and 3) 'Not a real question' since it's almost rhetorical in that the OP answers the question within the problem statement in a way that appears to be meant to persuade a future reader.

Comment: I added the note as it was too long to add in a comment. I wanted to convey what I meant with the term "optimization technique", not in an attempt to persuade any future reader. @whuber what do you mean by it is an idiosyncratic definition?  Furthermore, I'm not a specialist in parameter-fitting techniques, what would be an example of parameter fitting not involving optimization? Why should this question be closed, isn’t this a forum to ask questions with regards to statistics? Isn’t ambiguity in the use of a statistical terminology not also a valid question?

Comment: I believe @Macro has outlined the distinction in comments elsewhere in this thread: parameter fitting *uses* optimization but is not an *optimization technique* in its own right. But arguing over this is not the sort of thing that is appropriate for this site, which is why I am leaning towards closing the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is. In OLS, you are looking for the linear model that provides the "best" fit to the data. Implementation requires specifying some notion of what you mean by "best". OLS works by defining the "best" model as the one that minimizes a certain measure of model error -- in this case, the sum of the squares of the model residuals. The residuals are the part of the data that aren't explained by the model: OLS seeks to give the best description of the data, by minimizing the "total amount" of unexplained variation in the data.

Formally, any operaton in which you are solving for the minimum or maximum of some function can be interpreted as an optimization.

Comment: I think "optimization technique" is generally interpreted as referring to a method that can be used to optimize a given function. Yes, you are doing optimization when you solve for the OLS estimator but I don't see how that makes it an optimization _technique_. The Simplex algorithm, Newton's method, Conjugate-Gradient, etc... are optimization _techniques_.

Comment: @Macro is correct. OLS is (the solution to) an optimization problem. But given any optimization problem, there are a variety of techniques that one might use for solving it.

Answer (score 3):

I would have said that OLS is an optimization problem rather than an optimisation technique, as there are many optimization techniques/algorithms that can be used to solve OLS problems (e.g. analytical solutions for [ridge] regression, IRWLS for logistic regression, scaled conjugate gradients for neural nets, etc.).  There is no reason why you can't fit an OLS regression model by simple gradient descent, the reason we generally don't is there are more efficient algorithms.

OLS specifies what you are optimising, but you get the same solution from any suitable optimisation technique.

Answer (score 1):

Given explanatory variable $x_i$ and observed variable $y_i$, and a linear regression model $y = a + b x$, OLS is the minimum of: 
$$
\sum_i (y_i - b x_i - a)^2
$$
over all $a,b$.

In contrast to this, quantile regression is the minimum of:
$$
\sum_i |y_i - b x_i - a|
$$
over all $a,b$.

EDIT
As a minimum, the parameter estimates for $a$ and $b$ are some kind of optimum. And the [calculation method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29#Motivational_example), i.e. solving the normal equations, to actually find the estimates can be considered as technique.

So I vote for yes, OLS is a kind of optimization technique. If someone says "I solved the problem using OLS" I would conclude he used the euclidean norm and a linear solver on the normal equations formulation of the problem. I do not know which solver, though.

So the term "OLS" is more similar to "MLE" than to numerical methods like "Simplex algorithm" or "Conjugate Gradient method".

Comment: It looks like you've just defined what the OLS estimator is but, in it's current state, this doesn't seem to answer the question. Can you expand this post?

Comment: I think it's quite a good answer.  An optimization problem minimizes (or maximizes) some function.  That's the function for OLS.

Comment: @Patrick, I don't disagree with your statement _"An optimization problem minimizes (or maximizes) some function"_ but I don't see how that (or the content of the answer given by Karsten W.) relates to whether or not OLS would be considered an "optimization technique", which is what the question asks - all I see in this answer is the definition of the OLS estimator. Also, I'm not quite sure what you mean by _"That's the function for OLS."_ but if you're trying to say that OLS exists as a method of solving optimization problems, then that's not true; it's a method of estimation.

Comment: Sorry, I should be clearer.  I think the original question should be parsed as "is OLS a technique which employs optimization", rather than "is OLS a general technique for optimization".  The first is true, and if the first expression of KW's answer when reexpressed as a function is minimised by an optimizer the coefficent values will be identical to OLS estimation but for possible numerical issues.

Comment: @Patrick, It seems that an unconventional definition of "optimzation technique" is held by several people in this thread - I don't think you'll see anyone (e.g. wikipedia, a statistics textbook, etc.) referring to OLS or MLE as optimization techniques - you'll see them referred to as estimation techniques. We'll have to wait for clarification from the OP but I have a hard time seeing this as asking the first interpretation you gave, partially because "is OLS a technique which employs optimization" seems trivially true based on the name alone ("least squares"!!!).

Comment: @Marco: I don't think that your thread-brothers are trafficking in unconventional definitions. Rather, we are trying to provide what we understand the questioner is probably after.

Comment: In any event, whether a technique is/is not an optimization technique (or does/does not employ optimization) depends on formal definitions, not cultural conventions. (An order for pizza delivery _could be considered_, and is formally, a "financial contract", even if people don't generally think of it that way.)

Comment: @ArthurSmith, Honestly, I was using the term "unconventional" to be conciliatory - I'd be shocked to see any literature using the term "optimization technique" in the sense you are but I know for a fact the definition I'm ascribing to the term is used in various sources (e.g. the wiki page I linked above). Anyhow, my purpose here was to give food for thought to future readers of this thread and I have done that, so I will end my participation in this discussion - Cheers!

Comment: p.s. I do appreciate the concept of answering what you think the OP meant rather than what was actually written :) Related to that subject you may be interested in [this meta thread](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1397/strategies-for-answering-questions-that-may-be-unclear) about answering questions that may be ambiguous/unclear.

Comment: I am personally convinced OLS is an optimization technique, because it is applied to find optimal beta coefficients for a linear function that minimizes the squared prediction error over a set of instances. However, because the optimization is deterministic (derived from first order conditions) rather than algorithmic such as gradient decent, I'm having trouble explaining this.

Comment: @entropy, I'm not really following your reasoning but, FYI, you could also calculate the OLS estimator by using gradient descent (or any other optimization technique - just pick one) so don't let the fact that the OLS estimator happens to have a closed-form solution confuse the issue for you.

Comment: I know that I can also estimate the solve OLS estimators with other methods. That is exactly why I asked this question. Whether OLS estimation, given this closed form solution, is still considered optimization?

Comment: @entropy, I'm still having trouble following you but to answer the question posed by your final sentence - Yes, you are doing an optimization problem when you calculate the OLS estimator but, using the common definition of "optimization technique" (used in textbooks, wikipedia, etc...), No- OLS is not an optimization technique. Conjugate gradient, Newton-Raphson, Nelder-Mead Simplex, etc. are optimization techniques. This kind of non-constructive back and forth that really has nothing to do with statistics is the primary reason I think this question should be closed and subsequently deleted.

Comment: @Macro. Thank you very much for all your comments. I agree with you: the distinction between   estimators (noun) and the method of estimation (verb). However, if I applied a stepwise search for optimal values of beta coefficients that minimize the squared error function I would call this technique gradient decent. However in OLS I take partial derivatives with respects to each of the beta values, set equal to 0 to get first order condition, and solve the system of first order equation to get optimal beta values, what would I call this technique?

Comment: @entropy the technique of setting partial derivatives equal to zero is not OLS, just a method of solving a subset of OLS problems.  There are other optimisation problems you can solve by setting partial derivatives to zero and there are OLS problems that you can't solve this way (i.e. problems that are not linear in the parameters).

Comment: Yes i know. I'm just looking for the terminology for describing the method of setting partial derivatives to 0.